# Can't programmatically set NSConstraints on view

Tags: ios, autolayout

I'm trying to do something very simple:
Creating a view from scratch, adding it to the controller's view, and have it stretch edge to edge to its superview, but I get console warning once the app runs, saying the constraints cannot be simultaneously added to the view.

```
    backView = [UIView new];
    backView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [[self view] insertSubview:backView aboveSubview:tableview];
    [[self view] addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-0-[back]-0-|"
                                                                        options:0
                                                                        metrics:nil
                                                                          views:@{@"back": backView}]];

     [[self view] addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[back]-0-|"
                                                                         options:0
                                                                         metrics:nil
                                                                           views:@{@"back": backView}]];
```

Comment: Erm, is that a valid Visual Formating Language string:    "|-0-[back]-0-|"   don't you need to put "H:" in front so it becomes "H:|-0-[back]-0-|"  ?

Comment: H: is the default orientation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a `UIView` in code it `translates auto-resizing mask to constraints`.

i.e. it takes the frame you gave it when you created it and the auto-resizing mask and converts them into `NSLayoutConstraints`.

These auto-generated constraints are then conflicting with the constraints that you are adding manually.

If I'm right then you will be able to fix it by adding the line...

```
backView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

right after the first line and it should fix the problem.

Comment: Seems to work, thank you! They have to mention that in `addConstraint` documentation with superbold font :D

Comment: @Mabedan actually, it mentions it in the error message. It will say something like... `If you see NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint then it means you have to...` etc... can't remember off the top of my head. But that's the key to what you're looking for.